# Having issues with Invalid Writes

Tags: c++, pointers, valgrind

I just really need someone to tell me why this is incorrect.  I'm not versed in the ways of pointers to understand the fault I'm committing.

```
template <class T> UndoArray<T>::UndoArray(uint n)
{
    this->size_ = n;
    this->counts_ = new uint[n]; // this tells how many objs are in || values array
    values_ = new T*[n];
    //declare arrays in each spot of values_
    for(uint i=0; i<size_; ++i)  //HERE<=========
    {
        values_[n] = NULL;
    }
}
```

For some reason where I've said HERE I'm encountering an invalid write error on Valgrind.  Any time I write to these I appear to be getting them.  At one point the program even throws me a malloc error that says I've attempted to delete something that hasn't been allocated.

Comment: I think the main thing is using pointers to manage resources.

Comment: How this is related to C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
values_[n] = NULL;
```

On this line you're writing one past the end of the array you allocated. Perhaps you meant to use `values_[i]`?

Comment: I cannot even believe I did that and then bothered you all with it.  I'm bad and I should feel bad.  Thank you so much.  In t-minus 5min you'll get answer status.

Comment: No worries, it happens to everyone.